# Define hyperlink colors in a ConTeXt document

Tags: color, context

I am struggling setting hyperlink colors. I would like my TOC to be in a defined color which I try and set with `\startcolor[DCMBlue]` and `\stopcolor` around the TOC. All hyperlinks should be in `green` but on page 2, they are in red. What am I not understanding? Below is a MWE showing that the hyperlinks in the incorrect color:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\usemodule[lettrine]
\definecolor [DCMBlue][r=0.149, g=0.27, b=0.407]
\setupinteraction
[state=start,
color=green,
style=bold]

% Turn off page numbering as it is set in the footer
\setuppagenumbering[location=]
% Setup headers and footers
\setupfootertexts[][Page \userpagenumber of \lastuserpagenumber]

% Set up Cover Page
\defineoverlay[CoverPage]
              [{\externalfigure[cow][cow]}]

\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}]
\setuphead
  [section]
  [page=yes]

\starttext

\startfrontmatter

\setupbackgrounds[page][background={CoverPage}]
\startstandardmakeup

\stopstandardmakeup
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=]
\startcolor[DCMBlue]

% Insert TOC
\setupcombinedlist[content][list={chapter,section,subsection},alternative=c]
\completecontent
\stopcolor
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter




(See \in{Table}[tab:perf]) for details. .

\startplacetable[location=centre,reference=tab:perf,title=Historic Performance\footnote{this is a footnote}]

\bTABLE 
\bTR 
\bTD  \eTD 
\bTD Column 1 \eTD 
\bTD Column 2 \eTD 
\eTR 
\bTR 
\bTD Row 1 \eTD 
\bTD 1 \eTD 
\bTD 1 \eTD 
\eTR 
\bTR 
\bTD Row 2 \eTD 
\bTD 2 \eTD 
\bTD 2 \eTD 
\eTR 
\bTR 
\bTD Row 3 \eTD 
\bTD 3 \eTD 
\bTD 3 \eTD 
\eTR 
\eTABLE
\stopplacetable




\startsection[reference=sec:one,title={Section 1}]

\in{Table}[tab:perf]  the figures are shown.



\startsection[reference=title1,title={Title 1}]
\input ward
\page[yes]
\stopsection

\startsection[reference=title2,title={Title 2}]
\input ward
\page[yes]
\stopsection

\startsection[title={Title 3}]
\input ward
For the \color[green]{first} section see \at{page}[title1]

For the first section see \at{page}[title2]


\color[DCMBlue]{DCMBlueed text in TeX}
\page[yes]
\stopsection

\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

Comment: Use `\setupinteraction[state=start, color=green, contrastcolor=green]`, contrastcolor is used if the destination of the reference is on the same page as the reference.

Comment: @Marco : Thank you that works. Why is it in interactive documents when you hover over an element do you see a black framed box.

Comment: That depends on the PDF reader AFAIK, not ConTeXt related. If you believe it's a ConTeXt issue ask a new question to clarify or approach the mailing list.